# mySQL Query Returning duplicate results from INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need some help with a mySQL query I'm using in my php script. Seems I may be a bit confused on the way my INNER JOIN's are working.

```
SELECT * FROM CART_CARD
INNER JOIN INVOICE ON CART_CARD.cartID = INVOICE.cart_invoice_id
INNER JOIN PURCHASE_CARD ON PURCHASE_CARD.invoiceID = INVOICE.ID
WHERE CART_CARD.cardEmail = 'info@test.com'
AND PURCHASE_CARD.ID BETWEEN 26118 AND 26620
```

So there are 3 tables - CART_CARD, INVOICE, and PURCHASE_CARD.

PURCHASE_CARD has invoiceID, which matches up to INVOICE.ID.
INVOICE has a field card cart_invoice_id which matches up to CART_CARD.cartID.

I'm getting results, but it looks like the results are doubling and tripling the rows that are in CART_CARD. Does my query look right?

Results I'm getting back from CART_CARD. Please keep in mind that ID is the unique primary field. I've omitted the rest of the fields because it is sensitive information:

[image]

Comment: Always do `SELECT DISTINCT` unless you know exactly how and why duplicate rows are formed and that you want to have them. Normally, you don't.

Comment: Can you show sample data? If you have multiple matches on the JOIN columns, it's normal that you would get duplicate information from cart_card.

Comment: You're not providing enough information (showing the resultset would be helpful) but a good guess is that `PURCHASE_CARD` returns more than one record which makes the records returned from `INVOICE` and `CART_CARD` become duplicated.

Comment: Try to use a GROUP BY on the results duplicated.

Comment: I've provided a screen shot of the results back. It's just the primary ID and cartID.

Comment: @Joker_vD what you & zeflex are suggesting is called "programming by guessing" which is one of the worst way to program. If you don't get the expected result you should investigate why - not run all sorts of guesses until you reach the wanted result, cause there might be other things you're missing.

Comment: @tecshaun since you select `*` and we can see that the tables have other fields it looks weird that the resultset has only two fields. Please post the entire resultset if you want help.

Comment: @alfasin What I suggest is just using the SQL-equivalent of the operator from relational algebra.

Comment: I believe @alfasin might be right with his assumption. I'm looking into that now.

Comment: @Joker_vD The rest of the fields are sensitive information about users that I can not post.

Comment: @tecshaun if in the results you posted `ID` is a field taken from `PURCHASE_CARD` then you can see that there are multiple records in  `PURCHASE_CARD` which point to the same `cart-id` like I suggested earlier.

Comment: @alfasin You are right thank you. Is there an operator or something I could use to limit that?

Comment: @Joker_vD and zeflex just suggested `group by`, but both of you tried to "fix the result" instead of getting down to the source of the issue. Further, both your suggestions wouldn't work.

Comment: @tecshaun since there are multiple records that fit your query you should ask yourself which one is relevant. If the answer is that any of them will do - you can create a sub-query that pulls this one record from `PURCHASE_CARD` by using a combination of join with the relevant table and `LIMIT` the resultset to 1.

Comment: @alfasin And now *you* suggest `LIMIT 1`. I can bet $5 that he just has not partially identical, but completely identical rows in the result. If that's so, then `SELECT DISTINCT` is a perfectly valid solution. And if he has different (i.e. not completely equal) rows for one `id` value, then he has problems with the integrity so `GROUP BY` is as good as `LIMIT 1` since it works on probably-garbage-quality-data anyway, and the semantics of the query's output is undefined.

Comment: @Joker_vD You can convince me that you know what you're talking about by posting a valid answer that uses `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @alfasin Right after the questioner provides us with the schema. Without it that would be trying to guess the right answer while missing crucial information.

Comment: @Joker_vD excuses excuses... :) you got all you need in the question: `So there are 3 tables - CART_CARD, INVOICE, and PURCHASE_CARD.

PURCHASE_CARD has invoiceID, which matches up to INVOICE.ID. INVOICE has a field card cart_invoice_id which matches up to CART_CARD.cartID.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT DISTINCT FROM CART_CARD. showing only the unique records.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM CART_CARD CC, INVOICE INV, 
 (
 SELECT * FROM PURCHASE_CARD 
 WHERE ID BETWEEN 26118 AND 26620
 AND invoiceID = INV.ID 
 LIMIT 1
 ) PRC
WHERE CC.cartID = INV.cart_invoice_id
AND CC.cardEmail = 'info@test.com'
AND PRC.invoiceID = INV.ID
```

Comment: Overly complicated while DISTINCT would be sufficient.

Comment: @Nicolas assuming we can ignore all the other restrictions the OP posted in his query, you're right. This answer tries to cater both the DISTINCT requirement as well as the other ones which are reflected through the OP's query.